# How to modify iframe scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm trying remake (http://dollarz.comli.com/testing/index2.html) the design structure of https://www.seedlipdrinks.com/.

So I created a page with an iframe. But I've a problem with iframe scroll, it's not similar to the design that I'm trying to match.

I've tried using *scrolling="no"* attribute, but it's totally disabling the scroll.

I want the content inside iframe to be scrollable and the scroll bar should be hidden. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Are you want to allow scroll and hide scrollbar?

Comment: @MahmoodKohansal  yes.

Answer (score 2):

The site you linked does not use an iframe or any sort of scrolling container. It essentially has an opaque & fixed header & footer + margins for the main content. This is what make the site look contained in a rectangle, while preserving the ability to scroll using the window scroll bar. Here's how you can replicate the effect:

```
body {
  background-color: white;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}

section {
  padding: 50px 0; /* So the header/footer doesn't overlap the content */
  background-color: #7fff7f;
  margin: 0 50px;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/o3fLabhz/)

Comment: This seems to be a better option than using an iframe.

Comment: But the problem is if I set the height of header to 100%, it's occupying total space and other contents(like footer) are not showing. Here's how it's looking now (header -90vh, footer-10vh) -   http://dollarz.comli.com/scroll/index3.html . With iframe - http://dollarz.comli.com/scroll/index2.html .

Comment: Why are you setting the height of the header to 100%?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wrapper div around your iframe with style of `overflow: hidden`, and set your iframe width a little more than that div.

HTML :

```
<div style="overflow: hidden">
    <iframe src='http://dollarz.comli.com/testing/index.html'></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
iframe {
    width: 103%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahmoodkohansal/5GCsJ/5528/)

Comment: Cool trick. The only downside is that we can't use window scroll to scroll the contents of  iframe. http://dollarz.comli.com/scroll/index2.html

Comment: Unfortunately you are right. Also, your confirmation with checking the useful answer will help other users have this question like you.